# PostgreSQL full text search issue (to_tsquery)

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search

I'm having issues searching my database for game name that contains a stop word. I'm only looking for exact matches in general, I want as few "fuzzy" hits as possible for all my searching, optimally zero.

> E.g. content that produced false positives directly, contains sentences
>   like; "the war in Afghanistan" + reference to "win*" another place;
>   or "Lifeseed to win the war"; or "win the war that is taking over the
>   galaxy" and so on.

This of course does not work and gave an error:

```
SELECT id, title, content FROM my_table 
WHERE tsvector_combined@@ to_tsquery('win that war');
```

I had hoped "phraseto_tsquery" woudl work as it solved some of my other searches (PostgreSQL 9.6), but due to the stop word in this one it did not:

```
SELECT id, title, content FROM my_table 
WHERE tsvector_combined@@ phraseto_tsquery('win that war');
```

I also tried using the tie fighter thing, <1> | <-> but generally it gets the false positives:

```
SELECT id, title, content FROM my_table 
WHERE tsvector_combined@@ to_tsquery('win <-> that <-> war');
```

Is there any hack I can do here to get the the desired result of only having matches returned that is a phrase match? I was thinking maybe I could remove that as stop word, no idea how I do that and not sure how good a solution that is in light of maybe also searching for "World of Warcraft" and similar titles that has stop words (and that I in general only want exact matches).

Thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To remove some or all stopwords, create a reduced or empty stopword file in the `share/tsearch_data` subdirectory of the PostgreSQL software directory. Then you can create a new snowball text search dictionary with

```
CREATE TEXT SEARCH DICTIONARY newdict (
   TEMPLATE = pg_catalog.snowball,
   language = '...',
   stopwords = '...'
);
```

using your new stopword file and create a new text search configuration based on that. This will of course make your index larger.

From the examples you quote, I'd rather choose a different approach and use full text search to be able to use an index to reduce your candidates and further filter them with a second condition like this:

```
SELECT id, title, content FROM my_table 
WHERE tsvector_combined @@ to_tsquery('win that war')
  AND (title LIKE '%win that war%' OR content LIKE '%win that war%');
```

Comment: I will try this out, my first concern with your preferred option is maybe performance. The database in question will contain millions of article entries, does that change your recommended solutions?

Comment: No. The query with the additional `WHERE` clauses should not be much more expensive, because PostgreSQL will apply the indexed condition first and use the `LIKE` filters ony to process the result, which hopefully isn't too large. Of course, if the full text search returns a lot of results, things will be different, but then you have a problem with either approach.